# AJAX cannot POST to the endpoint

Tags: jquery, post

The below button is calling the jQuery function for post

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=login()>Login</button>
```

The next piece of code is the jquery function

```
<script>
function login() {
  console.log('Login Called')
  const finalData = ({"username":$('#name').val(),"paswword":$("#surname").val()})
  console.log('Data Sent for login ',JSON.stringify(finalData))
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3002/login',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(finalData),
            success: (data) => {
               console.log(data)
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

The last piece of code is the API of Express

```
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    const data = req.body
    console.log('Data Sent from front end ',data)
    connection.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM User WHERE email=? AND password=?',
                     [data.username,data.password],
        function(err,results,fileds){
            if(results.length===1)
            res.send({'message':'OK'})
            else if(results.length===0)
            res.send({'message':'No'})
        }
    )})
```

I am also posting the server endpoint requirements which I have mentioned above the endpoint just to make sure it is not one of them which is causing the problem.

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10);
var https = require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var fs = require('fs');
var config = require('./config.json');
server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var strFormat = require('string-format');
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.raw());
var connection = mysql.createConnection(config.sqlConn);   
console.log('Database Connected')
```

The API is working as I have post to the backend using Advanced RESTClient App and the endpoint is correctly returning values.
Also the data from the form is being correctly accessed by the jQuery function on button click. However, it is not posted to the endpoint. I have not used a whole lot of jQuery in my time so currently confused why is it happening. I would really appreciate some help as the POST function I created is the same as I did in one of my project in react.

Comment: Why do you have your json structure wrapped in brackets??

Comment: Do you see your console.log in login function ?

Comment: @Lk77 Yes. Its perfectly called. Both the console.log in the login function is correctly called. However, the console.log in the app.post function just does not print anything.

Comment: @DevMan Yeah I removed those. However the brackets is not a problem because when I do JSON.stringify the object is correctly structured.

Comment: Check the request in the network tab to see if something is wrong, you should see two requests, an OPTIONS request and a POST request, if cors are enabled.  If you api is on another domain/port it might be a cors issue. What is the status of your requests ? 200 ?? or something else ?

Comment: You are also using `$("#surname").val()` for the password. Is this fine?

Comment: @Lk77 So here is the thing the endpoint is reached when POST is done using google chrome but when it is done using Mozilla the endpoint is not reached. I just now tried with google chrome and I found that server console.log is printing out the data

Comment: Can someone please specify why Google chrome can reach the endpoint and not mozilla?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó yes it is correctly taking the values. I just copied the code from my other project and did not changed the ids thats all.